# Understanding a C version macro (looks like undeclared variable?)

Tags: c, macros, arduinojson

I happen to have read [`ArduinoJson/version.hpp`](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/blob/7.x/src/ArduinoJson/version.hpp), which contains the following macro:

```c
#define ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_MACRO V701
```

Now, I'm a python dev of very basic acquiantance with C from ctypes(gen).
To me it looks like `V701` is an undeclared variable, but this definitely seems intentional.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on? What is the purpose of this and why is the value not in quotes?

Comment: Search for `ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_MACRO` to see how it's used.

Comment: @user3386109 I had already done that but didn't understand any better afterwards: https://github.com/search?q=ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_MACRO&type=code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not used by itself as a value. In Namespace.hpp, you find the use:

```
#  define ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_NAMESPACE                                    \
    ARDUINOJSON_CONCAT4(ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_MACRO,                         \
                        ARDUINOJSON_BIN2ALPHA(ARDUINOJSON_ENABLE_PROGMEM,  \
                                              ARDUINOJSON_USE_LONG_LONG,   \
                                              ARDUINOJSON_USE_DOUBLE, 1),  \
                        ARDUINOJSON_BIN2ALPHA(ARDUINOJSON_ENABLE_NAN,      \
                                              ARDUINOJSON_ENABLE_INFINITY, \
                                              ARDUINOJSON_ENABLE_COMMENTS, \
                                              ARDUINOJSON_DECODE_UNICODE), \
                        ARDUINOJSON_SLOT_ID_SIZE)
```

Then searching for the definition of `ARDUINO_JSON_CONCAT4` you find:

```
#define ARDUINOJSON_CONCAT_(A, B) A##B
#define ARDUINOJSON_CONCAT2(A, B) ARDUINOJSON_CONCAT_(A, B)
#define ARDUINOJSON_CONCAT4(A, B, C, D) \
  ARDUINOJSON_CONCAT2(ARDUINOJSON_CONCAT2(A, B), ARDUINOJSON_CONCAT2(C, D))
```

So it's eventually used in token pasting, and will become part of the value of `ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_NAMESPACE`.

Comment: Thanks. But this kind of defers the question to `ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_NAMESPACE` for me. IIUC it will again be a "token", not a string value. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Presumably whatever it all concatenates to is defined somewhere. Or maybe it will be stringified. Go searching for how that macro is used.

Comment: Ah, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html made me get the gist of token pasting.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a macro where the string ARDUINOJSON_VERSION_MACRO will be substituted for V701 in the source by the c-pre-processor before the code is compiled.

Comment: Thanks, I had momentarily forgotten the preprocessor's behavior is just to paste in the defined piece of code.